# Help me understand behaviour when redefining \textbullet

Tags: macros

I have redefined `\textbullet` to make it a little larger (because the character used with the Libertinus font is very small compared to its Computer Modern equivalent), as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{libertinus}

% Resize \textbullet to make it a bit larger (closer to Computer Modern)
\let\oldbullet\textbullet
\renewcommand*\textbullet{{\large\oldbullet}}

\begin{document}
\oldbullet\textbullet$\mathord\bullet$
\end{document}
```

This works fine as far as achieving my main goal (`\textbullet` now produces a slightly larger version of itself). What I don't understand is why `\oldbullet` also shows up larger? I expected `\oldbullet` to produce a small bullet and `\textbullet` to produce a slightly larger one, because I was under the impression that using `\let` defined `\oldbullet` to be identical to the **original** definition of `\textbullet`. Clearly, that's not the case here.

I've tried to take a look at the LaTeX source files (`\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2022}{\textbullet}`) and to `\show` the definition (`->\?-cmd \textbullet \?\textbullet .`), but I don't understand enough to be able to figure out what either of those mean...

Any pointers as to where I should look next?

Comment: This feels so weird to me; and, if I redefine `\textbullet` to e.g. `{\oldbullet something}`, I get strange symbols after both bullets (with pdfLaTeX minus `libertinus`, that is; with LuaTeX it compiles fine—in fact, I can't reproduce the issue with LuaTeX). The [`letltxmacro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) package doesn't fix the issue with pdfLaTeX either. I'm really curious what's causing this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What’s going on here is that the definition of `\textbullet` looks several things up at the point of use, so trying to save the symbol with `\let` fails.

#### The Fix

If you’re compiling in a modern engine such as LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, the `libertinus` package loads `fontspec`, `unicode-math`, and the Unicode versions of the text and math fonts.

These fonts support the Unicode symbols ⚫, •, ∙, etc.  It even has `unicode-math` define the macros `\vysmblkcircle`, `\smblkcircle`, `\mdblkcircle`, etc. for them.  The Libertinus fonts have some but not all of these, so if you want to redefine `\textbullet` as the larger one, you want to first select a font that does contain it.  I chose DejaVu Sans.

If you’re compiling in a traditional TeX engine, such as PDFLaTeX, you want to define `\oldbullet` as slot `"88` of the TS1 encoding (essentially duplicating the old definition of `\textbullet` in `textcomp`, rather than saving the more complicated command in the modern LaTeX kernel).  If you’re going to be using a font that doesn’t come with a TS1 extension, you’d want to define `\textbullet` to select a font family and encoding along with the font size.  Since you’re using `libertinus` and no other font packages, that’s not a problem here.

However, you don’t want to select `\large` size all the time, even in, for example, a footnote.  What you more likely want is for the symbol to be one size larger than the current font.  You can accomplish this with `relsize`.

A sample:

```
\tracinglostchars=2 % Print a warning to the console if a character is missing.
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{libertinus}

\ifTUTeX
% The libertinus package loaded fontspec and unicode-math, with Libertinus
% Math as the math font.
  \newfontfamily\symbolfont{DejaVu Sans}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
  \DeclareTextSymbol{\oldbullet}{\UnicodeEncodingName}{"2022}
  \DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\oldbullet}{\UnicodeEncodingName}
  \renewcommand\textbullet{{\symbolfont\symbol{"26AB}}}
\else
% The libertinus package loaded the legacy Type 1 font.
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
  \usepackage{relsize}
  \DeclareTextSymbol{\oldbullet}{TS1}{"88}
  \DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\oldbullet}{TS1}
  \renewcommand\textbullet{{\larger\oldbullet}}
\fi

\begin{document}
\oldbullet\textbullet$\mathord\bullet$
\end{document}
```

If you also want U+2022 to be equivalent to `\textbullet` in text mode, and `\bullet` in math mode, you would add something like:

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{^^^^2022}{\ifmmode\bullet\else\textbullet\fi}
```

#### What’s Going on?

The LaTeX kernel declares `\textbullet` in one of three different encodings: the legacy symbol from the TS1 8-bit encoding, the even-older legacy symbol from the OMS 7-bit encoding, and the Unicode symbol.  This means the command for `\textbullet` doesn’t know ahead of time which font or encoding it will be using, and trying to save the definition with `\let` and then redefine `\textbullet` won’t work as expected.

The historical reason for this was that the bullet operator was first defined as a math symbol in the ’80s.  In 1996, Jörg Knappen defined a text-symbol encoding, TS1, as a companion for the new T1 Cork encoding.  However, the majority of fonts available at the time supported less than half of TS1.  As a bug workaround, for the next twenty years, LaTeX authors would load the `textcomp` package, which would attempt to detect the symbols the current font supported and fall back to poor-man’s versions if necessary.

There is no longer any need to load a separate package: this code is now in the LaTeX kernel.

The definition is documented in §20.4.1 of the LaTeX2e sources.  The relevant part is that `\DeclareTextCommand` expands to code that checks the current encoding and whether we are in math mode.  This refers to the `\?\textbullet` defined by `\DeclareTextCommandDefault`, which eventually expands in a recursive way.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `relsize`, which makes the redefined bullet useful in a wider range of contexts.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you just define the top-level `\oldbullet`, and it expands to `\?-cmd \textbullet \?\textbullet`, and that eventually expands to your redefined `\textbullet` which is `\large\oldbullet`.

As mentioned in the comment, this is basically the same issue as with robust commands: they are not *one single* macro, but a set of macros under similar name as the top-level macro, and when you redefine one, you have to redefine them all, otherwise you get an unwanted behaviour (this, however, isn't covered by `letltxmacro`).

To do what you want you can, instead of copying the definition of `\textbullet` to a new name, you can declare `\oldbullet` the same way as `\textbullet` is declared by LaTeX:

```
\DeclareTextSymbol{\oldbullet}{TS1}{136}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\oldbullet}{TS1}
```

The first line means that the command `\oldbullet` will take the character number `136` from the current font in encoding `TS1`, and the second line says that the default encoding for `\oldbullet` is `TS1`, so LaTeX changes the encoding if necessary to use that symbol (otherwise the symbol would always use the current encoding, no matter which it is).

Then you can redefine `\textbullet` normally:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{libertinus}

% Resize \textbullet to make it a bit larger (closer to Computer Modern)
\DeclareTextSymbol{\oldbullet}{TS1}{136}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\oldbullet}{TS1}
\renewcommand*\textbullet{{\LARGE\oldbullet}}

\begin{document}
\oldbullet\textbullet$\mathord\bullet$

\indent\kern1pt\raise5pt\hbox{$\smile$}
\end{document}
```

> [image]